# AngularJs controller in two separate files

Tags: angularjs, controller

In my `Javascript` file I have the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('allApps',['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      template: ''
    })
    .when('/user', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/user.html'
    })
    .when('/gallery', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/gallery.html'
    })
    .when('/contacts', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/contacts'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

Now, through ng-route I have another page called user.html that is simple this:

```
<div ng-controller = "Ctrl2">
    {{user.name}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   angular.module('allApps').controller('Ctrl2',function($scope){
      $scope.user={name:"Jim", lastname:"Smith"};
   });
</script>
```

In my `HTML` file I have the following code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/script.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But it doesn't work. **Error**:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl2&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
G/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
qb@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:22:131
Qa@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:22:218
Xe/this.$get</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:80:210
w@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:60:177
D@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:61:30
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105
K/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:54:249
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js:986:7
ea@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:73:293
D@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:62:190
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105
K/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:54:249
R/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:56:79
k@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:60:377
update@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js:936:25
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$broadcast@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:136:157
commitRoute/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js:619:15
f/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:119:129
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:133:309
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:130:404
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:76
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:87:442
T@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:92:50
Uf/</w.onload@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:93:78

<div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show a little more of how the page is structured?  Where is the tag for script.js versus the inline script block?

Comment: Also can you please share your routes config code?

Comment: I have a index.html where I have the tag script.js. Then I have a page called user.html that is just what I showed; all the site it's done through ng-route so everything is just in the index.html

Comment: @vas I edited the question, so you may see more details

Comment: Check out this: https://plnkr.co/edit/5ZpHE0O2wiZjnQUxAPxX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can't add controllers after angular is already bootstrapped, unless you use some kind of fancy lazy-loading. Therefore, adding a controller from a script block on a view is just not going to work.

Comment: So I can't even write the new controller in another js file? Because I tried but it doesn't work either.
Am I forced to write all in one file?

Comment: You can load it in another js file, but it has to be in a script tag on the page before angular compiles the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple controllers in differenct script files. But the script file should copile first before you start rendering the view.

Try binding your controller to the template view in the routes config

```
var app = angular.module('allApps',['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      template: '',
      controller: 'Ctrl1'
    })
    .when('/user', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/user.html',
      controller: 'Ctrl2'
    })
    .when('/gallery', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/gallery.html',
      controller: 'Ctrl3'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not closing your first function well. It should

```
var app = angular.module('allApps',['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Ctrl1',[ '$scope', function ($scope){
   ...
}]);
```

Comment: If I write inside my script.js 
app.controller('Ctrl2',function($scope){
     $scope.user={name:"Jim", lastname:"Smith"};
    });
it works. It's just something in the external file